# Action Script 3.0 Função não recebe parâmetro

Tags: actionscript-3, funções, flash, parâmetros

Estou tendo um problema com parâmetros para minha função. Ela não está recebendo o parâmetro que eu passo para ela. Segue o código abaixo:

```
function gerarescala(e:MouseEvent):void
{

var tom:String = texto.text;
var escala:Array = new Array('C','C#','Db', ...);
var container:Array = new Array([vazio]); //Este array vai receber elementos de acordo com os elementos do array escala.
var pesquisa,i:Number;

[Aqui vai o Código preenchendo o array container] ...

[A função "imp", é muito extensa, então esse é só um trecho, mas é a mesma coisa em  toda a função]

 function imp(pos:String):String {

  var retorno:String;

if (pesquisa == 1)
{
    if (pos == "D#")
    {
        retorno = container[3];
    }
    else if (pos == "F")
    {
        retorno = container[6];
    }

return retorno;

  }//fim func imp

}//Fim func grarescala
```

Ao decorrer do código que quero fazer, vou chamar a função da seguinte maneira: imp(container[3]); passando um elemento do array container para minha função, porem eu testei isso e quando executo vejo que ela me volta "null". já verifiquei com entradas de "string" diretas e funcionou, ela só não funciona com esse parâmetro de array que passo para ela.
O resto de código esta tudo funcionando e esta tudo certo, a única coisa que esta dando problema é com o parâmetro.

Eu observei que a função imp não esta vendo o array container, e já coloquei a função imp fora da função principal, porem se fizer isso a função imp não vai ver nenhuma variável, e se eu tirar as variáveis da função principal ela não vai funcionar do jeito que quero.

Alguma sugestão ??

Comment: Tem como colocar o código completo em algum lugar? (ex.: pastebin) Só de olhar o trecho que você postou não dá pra identificar onde pode estar o problema...

Comment: @mgibsonbr Como eu disse a função "imp()" é muito extensa. O código seguinte seria:

Comment: apenas a chamada da função por sete vezes, imprimindo na tela. imp(container[3] ... imp(container[6] ... imp(container[7] ... container[10] por diante. Como eu disse o real problema é o parâmetro que passo para função, e acontece com o parâmetro elemento de array[];

Comment: Não estou falando pra colocar o código completo aqui, e sim pra postar em algum lugar (pastebin, ideone, etc) e colocar o link aqui. Você *afirma* que o problema está na passagem de parâmetro, mas como podemos ter certeza (e te ajudar) se não conhecemos seu código?

Comment: Gostaria de te ajudar @FenixDK, mas não entendi nada do seu código, poste em algum lugar o código ou edite sua pergunta para torná-lo mais compreensível.

Comment: @mgibsonbr, Bom desculpe a confusão, o código inteiro esta aqui: http://pastebin.com/R4Uj1Ra8

Comment: Blz, agora está mais claro, +1. Quanto à chamada de `imp`, você tem um exemplo do que funciona e do que não funciona? Por exemplo, se `tom` (`texto.text`) for "C#", `imp("D#")` retorna `"D#"` e `imp(container[3])` retorna `null`. É isso?

Comment: Oque acontece neste código, é: tom é uma entrada de usuário, e a partir dai o array container vai ser preenchido de acordo com essa entrada. o padrão de verificação, o que vai passar pela função e ser analisado é alguns elementos do container, ex: imp(container[3]); de acordo com o que esta no container[3] a função imp() vai me retornar de acordo com que eu quero. Só que a função imp() funciona de acordo com a variável "pesquisa" mas ela não esta acessando essa variável assim como o array container.

Comment: @mgibsonbr enquanto sua pergunta do que funciona, a única coisa que não esta funcionando é essa parte do parâmetro como array[]. Como string direta funciona ex: imp("D"). já testei com alguns "trace". mas a imp() me retorna null quando passo para ela como array[].

Comment: Eu acho improvável, pois até onde eu saiba ActionScript lida corretamente com closures. De todo modo, uma sugestão: que tal definir `imp` de modo que ela receba `pesquisa` e `container` como parâmetros adicionais, em vez de acessar essas variáveis do escopo externo? Veja se isso ajuda em alguma coisa. Pessoalmente, estou "apostando" num erro de lógica em vez disso, mas não tenho certeza. Repare por exemplo que nem toda entrada produz uma resposta não nula, e que há certos índices repetidos - como `C` e `C#`, ambos `1` - e outros que parecem incorretos, como `D#`, `5`.

Comment: Nesta parte, creio que não há erros porque esse código é o mesmo que fiz em PHP. Quanto aos índices vou verificar uma otimização.

Comment: Estava testando uma coisa aqui no código, e descobri que o container tem um problema apesar dele estar preenchido. var var1:String = container[3]; declarei essa variável para testar e quando imprimo isso, me retorna "null". sabe me dizer se o erro pode ser manipulação de array ?

Comment: @FenixDK Pelo que eu vi no seu código, a criação de `container` parece estar correta. `escala` está funcionando? Eu notei que o array `container` é desnecessário (ainda que útil) - você pode substituir `container[i]` por `escala[(i + pesquisa) % 17]` para qualquer `i`. Desde é claro que `pesquisa` esteja com um valor válido. (A propósito, você verificou isso? Não conheço ActionScript muito bem, o único `indexOf` que eu conheço é pra procurar uma substring dentro de uma string. Ele funciona com arrays também?)

Comment: Sim, "indexof" funciona como um "array_search" do PHP

Comment: Não é necessário levar em consideração a verificação de entradas agora. Não terei problemas quanto a isso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De acordo com [esse *thread*](http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=186178), o método `indexOf` não serve para buscar em um array, somente em uma string.

```
var m: Array = ["CYCLE", "FREE", "EASY"];
//
var index:Number;
index= m.indexOf("FREE");
trace("INDEX "+index); // traces undefined
index= m[1].indexOf("FREE");
trace("INDEX "+index); // traces 0
```

Isso não explica o erro que você está encontrado (pelo meu entendimento do seu código, `container` ainda deveria conter elementos válidos apesar do erro - só a ordem é que estaria errada), mas deve estar contribuindo para ele. Ainda segundo o *thread* linkado, o problema pode estar nas diferenças de versão do ActionScript.

De todo modo, [esse outro *thread*](http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=50452) sugere usar um meio mais "direto" de se buscar um array por uma elemento:

```
for ( i = 0 ; i < escala.length ; i++ )
    if ( escala[i] == tom )
        pesquisa = i;
```

Assegurando-se que `pesquisa` está correto, o problema com `container` deve se resolver também. Mas de todo modo, note que você *não precisa* desse array auxiliar: tudo o que você está fazendo é deslocar o array `escala` X posições à esquerda, baseado no `tom` buscado. Dessa forma, toda expressão da forma:

```
container[i]
```

Pode ser substituída por:

```
escala[(i + pesquisa) % 17]
```

Usando o cálculo com o módulo. Você pode também usar `escala.length` em vez de `17` para eliminar esse "número mágico". Entretanto, creio que é mais *conveniente* pra você usar um array auxiliar mesmo - ou senão uma função que faça esse cálculo pra você (pra não ter que ficar repetindo essa expressão complicada toda vez).

Comment: Vou fazer os testes aqui muito obrigado pelas respostas!